# In React and Typescript why are my absolute paths not working on nested folders?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, absolute-path

I'm trying to set up absolute paths in my React project but am running into a few issues when it comes to nested folders and the use of `@` prefix.

With the following settings in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions":{
    "baseUrl":"src",
    "paths":{
      "global/*":[
        "./global/*"
      ],
      "features/*":[
        "./features/*"
      ],
      "content/*":[
        "./features/content/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include":[
    "src"
  ]
}
```

This works:
`import "features/content/css/viewContent.css";`

But this does not:
`import "content/css/viewContent.css";`

I'm also having issues when using `@` prefix, for example with the following settings in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions":{
    "baseUrl":"src",
    "paths":{
      "global/*":[
        "./global/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include":[
    "src"
  ]
}
```

This works:
`import "global/components/example";`

But adding a `@` prefix in my settings liks so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions":{
    "baseUrl":"src",
    "paths":{
      "@global/*":[
        "./global/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include":[
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Doesn't work:
`import "@global/components/example";`

File structure for examples above is as follows:

```
└── root dir
    ├── src
    │   └── features
    │       ├── content
    │           └── css
    │           └── etc...
    │           └── etc...
    │           └── etc...
    │   └── global
    │       ├── components 
    │       └── etc...
    │       └── etc...
    │       └── etc...
    │  
    └── tsconfig.json
```

I've also followed the steps
[here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but unfortunaley with not much luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue caused by using create-react-app. I managed to solve it by using [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) and adding the paths to my `craco.config.js` (as well as having them in my `tsconfig.json` file)

**craco.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    alias: {    
      "@global": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/global/"),
      // etc...     
    },
  },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
  // etc...
  "baseUrl": "src",
  "paths": {
    "@global/*": ["./global/*"],
  }
// etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server you are using to run your app.

I have the same issue with **Vite**, and there's actually a lib made for that : vite-tsconfig-paths

But I don't like to import libraries for minor issues like this one.

Comment: Very slow reply but thanks, I've jumped over to **Vite** now and `vite-tsconfig-paths` makes life a lot easier!

Comment: Well in the meantime I got used to simply add my path in both tsconfig.json and vite.config.js like the previous answer.
It's almost the same thing on both side, it's annoying to duplicate a config but at least it works without any other lib